# Array items check as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, onclick, visible

I have 4 movieclips in an array

```
var tiles:Array = new Array("tile1","tile2","tile3","tile4");
```

Inside each one there is code to vanish when it's clicked with the mouse on the second frame.

```
this.visible = false;
```

From the main timeline is the control for the mouse click for each of the tiles (only the first one is displayed).

```
tile1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_);

function fl_(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    tile1.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

How can I make it so when all the tiles in the array become invisible, flash to take action (such as to go to frame 5)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at your .fla.  Here are two ways to do what you'd like:

On Your Main Timeline: (replace the current main timeline frame 1 code with the following)

```
stop(); 

//loop through every child of the `cont` container, and add the same click listener
var i:int = cont.numChildren
while(i--){
    var tile:MovieClip = cont.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
    if(tile){
       tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tileClick, false,0,true);
    }
}

function tileClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //this gets a reference to one that was clicked
    var tile:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

    tile.gotoAndStop(2);

    //loop through the tile array to see if any are still visible
    var i:int = cont.numChildren
    while(i--){
        tile = cont.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
        if(tile && tile.currentFrame == 1) return;
    }

    //if we got this far, all the tiles are hidden, lets go to frame 5.
    gotoAndStop(5);
}
```

---

If the above is intimidating and you would prefer to keep it like it was before, then this is all you'd have to do:  (again, this code will replace your current main timeline frame 1 code)

```
stop();

cont.tile1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tileClick);
cont.tile2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tileClick);
cont.tile3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tileClick);
cont.tile4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tileClick);

function tileClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    MovieClip(e.currentTarget).gotoAndStop(2);
    if(cont.tile1.currentFrame == 1) return;
    if(cont.tile2.currentFrame == 1) return;
    if(cont.tile3.currentFrame == 1) return;
    if(cont.tile4.currentFrame == 1) return;

    //if we got this far, all the tiles are hidden, lets go to frame 5.
    gotoAndStop(5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I was simply asking, how can i go to frame 5 without changing the current configuration. It has to go to frame 2 inside the tile, and these tiles are actually inside a container mc. I was hoping that from the answer here I'll figure out the rest, but now it became way more difficult, anyway thanks. Here is the file by the way: https://app.box.com/files/0/f/0/1/f_21071986269

Comment: I'm not sure what else you're looking to do?  Making the tile that was clicked go to frame 2 is easy enough (I updated the answer), what else are you struggling with?

Comment: I have  tile.visible = false; on the second frame inside the tile. To go to that frame 2 i have cont.tile1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_);

function fl_(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    tile1.gotoAndStop(2);
}      And like that I have 4 tiles inside mc called "cont". Once they are all clicked and are invisible I need to take action like for example to go to frame 5 on the main timeline. That is all! I am not sure if array is needed. Thanks.

Comment: If the only children of `cont` is the 4 tiles, then you could do it the same way but without the array.   There's no reason you can't go back to adding a separate listener for all 4 tiles like you were doing before, it's just more code (and if you want to change something later you have to change it in 4 different places instead of 1)

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/psg9ocy475j4ymowcme6 This is the file actually. No it has to be in this configuration, because that container mc is going to be a level to a game. I only want to go to frame 5 when they are all invisible. This has turned into enormously challenging task and has been a dream for me for over a week already

Comment: I looked at your .fla and upaded the answer. Tried both ways I posted and they work.

Comment: Thank you So much you are great! It is so much simpler!